# How to use turicreate in Anaconda navigator

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, turi-create

I created a new conda environment and installed turicreate. How can I start anaconda navigator within this new environment? Currently I start navigator from the base environment and then switch to the new environment. When I do this, I can see turicreate is listed as an installed package, but when I import it, I get a modulenotfound error.

Comment: _When I do this, I can see turicreate is listed as an installed package, but when I import it, I get a modulenotfound error._ Is that related to Anaconda Navigator though?

Comment: I'm a novice and just installed anaconda navigator, so I'm not familiar with how it works. However, it recognized the new conda environment and found turicreate in the package list, so I suspected it should import to python.

Comment: Did you ever work things out?

Comment: I had to create an environment with python 3.7. Default navigator install is with python 3.8 and turicreate doesn't work with 3.8. After installing 3.7 I was able to install turicreate using pip

Comment: You should post an answer to this question, then, or delete it if you think it won't be useful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating new environment with a version of python (3.7) compatible with Turicreate solved this problem..